# ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse-CVS

Tags: java, liferay

My Liferay Project named `Project A` is dependent to another project from CVS repossitory named `Project B`,

I am getting this `ClassNotFoundException` each time I use classes inside the `Project B` which is the project from CVS. I don't understand why, I also included the `Project B` in my project's build path but doesn't work.

Please help me, how can I use the classes inside the project from repository? Here is the `Stack Trace` of the `exception` that is thrown:

```
05:28:44,714 ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fluxion.profileservice.DAOImpl.EnrolledCustomerDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.service.EnrolledCustomerService.getCustomerIDList(EnrolledCustomerService.java:10)
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.portlet.OrderTaggingPortlet.doView(OrderTaggingPortlet.java:43)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

05:28:49,669 ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fluxion/profileservice/DAOImpl/EnrolledCustomerDAOImpl
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.service.EnrolledCustomerService.getCustomerIDList(EnrolledCustomerService.java:10)
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.portlet.OrderTaggingPortlet.doView(OrderTaggingPortlet.java:43)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)

Loading file:/C:/liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0.6-20110225/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/chat-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/portlet.properties
05:28:49,777 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1230] Checking for available updates
05:28:49,780 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1274] Finished checking for available updates in 2 ms
05:32:02,296 ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fluxion/profileservice/DAOImpl/EnrolledCustomerDAOImpl
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.service.EnrolledCustomerService.getCustomerIDList(EnrolledCustomerService.java:10)
    at com.fluxion.myaccounts.portlet.OrderTaggingPortlet.doView(OrderTaggingPortlet.java:43)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
```

Comment: have you checked out both Projects A & B in eclipse? It would be great if you can also tell about what packages are taken as `source` packages in both projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the classes from project B are accessible during compiling but not at run time. To get this working you have several approaches:

1. Simpy: get the two projects together to one project. That is the simplest way, you put multiple portlets and hooks in one project. Than all you classes will be load by one classloader.
2. If you need shared classes, that will be load by several projects - create a project that contains only java classes (no portal configuration like portlet.xml etc.). Export this shared project to jar file and put the jar file in other projects (like your Project A) in `docroot/WEB-INF/lib` folder. If the shared classes have shared state, then put the jar file uniquely to tomcat shared folder like `tomcat/lib/ext/`